# Undefined symbol issue with Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am writing a Makefile and I have a Views.h with functions being declared in it that are being called in Views.cpp. Views.cpp `#includes "Views.h"`, so I am sure I am linking them correctly.

However, I still get a bunch of undefined reference errors in my Views.cpp when I run the make command. The undefined reference errors are all regarding the functions in Views.h.

I believe the problem is that the functions in View.h are being declared there, not actually defined or implemented, and are actually in a .lib file in a folder called `Library` in my project directory.

My issue then is how do I write a Makefile that links the .lib file to my Views.h file, so that my Views.cpp can use the functions?

Also, I have the corresponding .dll file as well. I understand both are library files, 1 is dynamic and the other is static. But how do I link them?

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]. Judging by what you have provided, you probably need to provide the .lib file as an argument to the compiler, but I can't tell for sure without your code.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between compiling and linking?

Comment: Attach your .h .cpp and Makefile. Maybe remove all functins except one which still produces undefined reference.

Comment: _Views.cpp #includes "Views.h", so I am sure I am linking them correctly._ `#include` has nothing to do with linking.  You still need to link with the correct object files and / or libraries.  If you copy and paste your error messages into your question you might get more help.